# Lipschitz constant for a multivariate function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lipschitz-functions

I need to compute a Lipschitz constant for the function:
$$
F(x,y)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{3}x^3+2xy\\
x^2+3xy
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $(x,y)\in[0,2]^2$. My first thought was to use the mean value theorem, and compute the operatornorm of the derivative. However this soon became very complicated.

So now I'm at a loss and can't figure out what to do. So how would one solve such a problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need a number $K$ with 
$$
\|F(x_1, y_1) - F(x_0, y_0)\| \le K D
$$
where $D$ is the distance between the two points.

Letting $F_1(x, y) = x^3/3 + 2xy$, and similarly for $F_2$, the difference between $F_1(x_0, y_0)$ and $F_1(x_1, y_1)$ is no greater than the distance between the domain points, multiplied by the maximum magnitude of the gradient of $F_1$ on your rectangle. You can compute that max.

You can do the same for $F_2$. And then you can use these to estimate the max change in $(F_1, F_2)$ by the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you refer to Example 54.7 in section Lipschitz Continuity of the article [1]. The example is $F(\mathbf{x})=
\begin{pmatrix}
f_1(\mathbf{x}) \\
f_2(\mathbf{x})
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 + x_2 \\
x_1x_2
\end{pmatrix}$,
where $\mathbf{x}=[x_1,x_2]$. The article shows that $||F(\mathbf{x})-F(\mathbf{y})||^2 \leq ||f_1(\mathbf{x})-f_1(\mathbf{y})||^2 + ||f_2(\mathbf{x})-f_2(\mathbf{y})||^2 \leq L_1^2 ||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}||^2 + L_2^2 ||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}||^2$, and we have $||F(\mathbf{x})-F(\mathbf{y})||^2 \leq L ||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}||$ where $L = \sqrt{L_1^2 + L_2^2}$.

[1] Vector-Valued Functions of Several Real Variables.